# How to update firebase data, as it returns new undefined value at end of tree

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I need to update, value of an data.

[image]

I need to update, orderStatus. But when i use update, it creates new item as "undefined" at bottom of the tree.

Here is the code:

```
admin.auth().getUser(phone)
    .then(() => {
        return  admin.database().ref(`orders/${phone}/${uid}`)
            .update({ orderStatus: "Hair" });
    })
    .catch((err)=> res.status(422).send({ error:err }) );
```

How to update the already existing data. Is my code wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what value `phone` is, but if it (as its name suggests) is a phone number, then you'll want to use [`getUserByPhoneNumber`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUserByPhoneNumber) instead of `getUser()`.

Comment: It's impossible for us to know `phone` and `uid` are, but from the results it seems that at least one of them has an `undefined` value. For better help, see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I would help if a complete snippet of your Firebase structure was included. Please do not include images and links in questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to update the whole node. When I did something similar this was my code.

```
  const updateObj ={}
      if (payload.welcome){
        updateObj.welcome = payload.welcome
      }
      if(payload.description){
        updateObj.description = payload.description
      }
      if(payload.date){
        updateObj.date = payload.date
      }
      firebase.database().ref('/users/' + getters.user.id).child('/displays').child(payload.id).update(updateObj);
```

Try cloning your object then alter that one field and push the new object in the update.

Answer (score 0):

The `getUser` method gets a user by their UID. From the [reference docs for `Auth.getUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUser):

> Gets the user data for the user corresponding to a given `uid`.

If your `phone` variable (as its name suggests) is a phone number, then you'll want to use [`getUserByPhoneNumber`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUserByPhoneNumber) instead of `getUser()`.

```
admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(phone)
  ...
```

Comment: actually, i assigned phone as uid while creating new user. So its not an issue